# GitHub private repo with collaborator with read access: what can he do in issues?

Tags: github

We have a private repo in our org on GitHub and I've invited some external user to this repo. I have him the "Read" access. He can now **read** and **clone** the repo (I guess the clone will stay private, right?).

What can he do inside **issues**?

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://help.github.com/articles/what-are-the-different-access-permissions/

Comment: Yes, it's not described there (unless I missed it somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the [permission levels](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/) a collaborator (inside or outside of the organisation) can:

> > Open, close, re-open, and assign issues

Haven't tried it out. But it sounds meaningful to me.

Comment: That article is about "A repository owned by a user account" - the question is about the org repo. You can give the collaborator Read, Write and Admin access. I don't see it detailed anywhere in the docs.